# Use vte Pygobject inside flatpak

Tags: flatpak, flatpak-builder

I been trying to use vte inside my flatpak but, when I run it inside flatpak I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bin/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Vte', '2.91')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 126, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Vte not available
```

How can I fix it? I'm using the Gnome platform and sdk 44.
Flatpak manifest:

```
app-id: io.github.gssh_linux.gssh
runtime: org.gnome.Platform
runtime-version: '44'
sdk: org.gnome.Sdk
command: runner.sh
finish-args:
  - --share=network
  - --socket=x11
  - --share=ipc
modules:
  - name: Gssh
    buildsystem: simple
    build-commands:
      - install -D Flatpak/runner.sh /app/bin/runner.sh
      - install -D main.py /app/bin/main.py
      - install -D Flatpak/.desktop /app/share/applications/io.github.gssh_linux.gssh.desktop
      - install -D Flatpak/appicon.png /app/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/io.github.gssh_linux.gssh.appicon.png
      - install -D Flatpak/io.github.gssh_linux.gssh.appdata.xml /app/share/metainfo/io.github.gssh_linux.gssh.appdata.xml

    sources:
      - type: git
        url: https://github.com/gssh-linux/gssh.git
        tag: 1.1.8


  - name: org.gnome.Platform
    version: 44
    runtime: org.gnome.Platform
    sdk: org.gnome.Sdk
    override: true
    build-options:
      # Add the Vte extension
      - --share=lib/vte
```

I tried adding the vte extension but it was the same

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Vte is not included in the SDK and needs to be added with a separate module. You can do this by changing your manifest to contain

```
modules:
   - name: vte
     sources:
       - type: git
         url: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte.git/
         commit: 5bf476f1d7283bc805ac8ae6abe94f81ffd7be05
     buildsystem: meson
     config-opts:
       - -Dgtk3=false
       - -Dgtk4=true
```